# How can I evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{x}^{x^2}{\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Well I've heard of Leibniz integral rule but don't quite understand it. Other than that I've no idea for how this can be solved given that $\mbox{sinc}(x)$ is an improper integral.

Also, I've used Wolfram Alpha and it states that the solution is $2x\mbox{sinc}(x^2)-\mbox{sinc}(x)$ but I've no idea how it computed the answer?

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Note that the variable used for integration should be different from the variable in the bounds; eg $\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{x^2}\frac{\sin t}{t}\;dt$.

Comment: @stewbasic corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. You probably know the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part):
if $f$ is a continuous function in $[x_0, x]$ then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{x_0}^{x}f(t) dt=f(x).$$
Moreover, note that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{x}^{x^2}{\frac{\sin t}t\,dt}=
\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{1}^{x^2}{\frac{\sin t}t\,dt}-\frac{d}{dx}\int_\limits{1}^{x}{\frac{\sin t}t\,dt}.$$
Now be careful with the first derivative.

Comment: can we break the limits $x$ to $x^2$ into $x$ to $a$ and $a$ to $x^2$ for any value of $a$ instead of 1(the one you used) and the result will be same?

Comment: In this case the function $\sin t/t$ can be extended continuously at 0 with the value $1$. So it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and you can break the integral whereever you want.

Comment: One more question- in the first integral, why we have to multiply the result  of second integral by $\frac{d}{dx}x^2$? Appears like some type of chain rule.

Comment: It is the chain rule. Let $F(x)=\int_\limits{x_0}^{x}f(t) dt$, then you are deriving $F(x^2)$.

Comment: Many many thankx Robert